# SQLite 3: sqlite InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 python modules and th following code returns the error

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\MonitorSoft\MonitorSoft.py", line 199, in LoadSQL
>     CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0],
> option='values')[3],))
> 
> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably
> unsupported type.

def LoadSQL(event):
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:/MonitorSoft/SoftMon.db')
    CurPackets = con.cursor()
    CurFiles = con.cursor()
    CurFilesIn = con.cursor()
    curFilesPackets = con.cursor()
    CurPackets.execute('SELECT * FROM Packets WHERE PacketName = ?', (WinRedactor.Combobox.get(),))
    for RowPackets in CurPackets:
        if WinRedactor.Combobox.get() !='NULL':
            while WinRedactor.Table.selection() != '':
                CurFilesIn.execute('INSERT INTO Files (id, FilePath, FileName, Size, CheckSum) VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)',((WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[0]), (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[1]), (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[2]),(WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3])))
                con.commit()
                    CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3],))
                for RowFiles in CurFiles:
                    if RowFiles[4] == (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3]):
                        curFilesPackets.execute('INSERT INTO FilesPackets (IDFile, IDPacket) VALUES(?,?)',((RowFiles[0]), (RowPackets[0])))
                        con.commit()
                WinRedactor.Table.delete(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0])
        con.commit()
        con.close()

BtnLoadSQL = Button(WinRedactor)
BtnLoadSQL["text"] = "LOAD SQL"
BtnLoadSQL.bind("<Button-1>",LoadSQL)
BtnLoadSQL.pack()
```

What the problem?

Concluded the data as you wrote.
The data are the same everywhere.
The error appears randomly on different lines.
Here's an example of what gives the output as you wrote:

```
selection is ('I04C', 'I04D', 'I04E', 'I04F', 'I050', 'I051', 'I052', 'I053', 'I054', 'I055', 'I056', 'I057', 'I058', 'I059', 'I05A', 'I05B', 'I05C', 'I05D', 'I05E', 'I05F', 'I060', 'I061', 'I062', 'I063', 'I064', 'I065', 'I066', 'I067', 'I068', 'I069', 'I06A', 'I06B', 'I06C', 'I06D', 'I06E', 'I06F', 'I070', 'I071', 'I072', 'I073', 'I074', 'I075', 'I076', 'I077', 'I078', 'I079', 'I07A', 'I07B', 'I07C', 'I07D', 'I07E', 'I07F', 'I080', 'I081', 'I082', 'I083', 'I084', 'I085', 'I086', 'I087', 'I088', 'I089', 'I08A', 'I08B', 'I08C', 'I08D', 'I08E', 'I08F', 'I090', 'I091', 'I092', 'I093', 'I094', 'I095', 'I096', 'I097', 'I098', 'I099', 'I09A', 'I09B', 'I09C', 'I09D', 'I09E', 'I09F', 'I0A0', 'I0A1', 'I0A2', 'I0A3', 'I0A4', 'I0A5', 'I0A6', 'I0A7', 'I0A8', 'I0A9', 'I0AA', 'I0AB', 'I0AC', 'I0AD', 'I0AE', 'I0AF', 'I0B0', 'I0B1', 'I0B2', 'I0B3', 'I0B4', 'I0B5', 'I0B6', 'I0B7', 'I0B8', 'I0B9', 'I0BA', 'I0BB', 'I0BC', 'I0BD', 'I0BE', 'I0BF', 'I0C0', 'I0C1', 'I0C2', 'I0C3', 'I0C4', 'I0C5', 'I0C6', 'I0C7', 'I0C8', 'I0C9', 'I0CA')
first selection is I04C
values are ('C:\\WINDOWS\\Resources\\Themes\\Luna\\Shell\\Metallic', 'shellstyle.dll', '362496', '05b3f32c7f3bd125446d024a30373c9d')
checksum: 05b3f32c7f3bd125446d024a30373c9d
selection is ('I04D', 'I04E', 'I04F', 'I050', 'I051', 'I052', 'I053', 'I054', 'I055', 'I056', 'I057', 'I058', 'I059', 'I05A', 'I05B', 'I05C', 'I05D', 'I05E', 'I05F', 'I060', 'I061', 'I062', 'I063', 'I064', 'I065', 'I066', 'I067', 'I068', 'I069', 'I06A', 'I06B', 'I06C', 'I06D', 'I06E', 'I06F', 'I070', 'I071', 'I072', 'I073', 'I074', 'I075', 'I076', 'I077', 'I078', 'I079', 'I07A', 'I07B', 'I07C', 'I07D', 'I07E', 'I07F', 'I080', 'I081', 'I082', 'I083', 'I084', 'I085', 'I086', 'I087', 'I088', 'I089', 'I08A', 'I08B', 'I08C', 'I08D', 'I08E', 'I08F', 'I090', 'I091', 'I092', 'I093', 'I094', 'I095', 'I096', 'I097', 'I098', 'I099', 'I09A', 'I09B', 'I09C', 'I09D', 'I09E', 'I09F', 'I0A0', 'I0A1', 'I0A2', 'I0A3', 'I0A4', 'I0A5', 'I0A6', 'I0A7', 'I0A8', 'I0A9', 'I0AA', 'I0AB', 'I0AC', 'I0AD', 'I0AE', 'I0AF', 'I0B0', 'I0B1', 'I0B2', 'I0B3', 'I0B4', 'I0B5', 'I0B6', 'I0B7', 'I0B8', 'I0B9', 'I0BA', 'I0BB', 'I0BC', 'I0BD', 'I0BE', 'I0BF', 'I0C0', 'I0C1', 'I0C2', 'I0C3', 'I0C4', 'I0C5', 'I0C6', 'I0C7', 'I0C8', 'I0C9', 'I0CA')
first selection is I04D
values are ('C:\\WINDOWS\\Resources\\Themes\\Luna\\Shell\\NormalColor', 'shellstyle.dll', '361472', '23ecf1c97b1eb5d94a25dc677ec464e5')
checksum: 23ecf1c97b1eb5d94a25dc677ec464e5
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\MonitorSoft\MonitorSoft.py", line 213, in LoadSQL
CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (checksum,))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

This is the last two conclusions, at last, as you can see there is a bug.

Comment: Can you check those values are right? `WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3],)`

Comment: So what does `print(type(WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3]))` produce? What about `print(repr(WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3]))`?

Comment: It handles a number of records and then gives an error
<class 'str'>
'05b3f32c7f3bd125446d024a30373c9d'
<class 'str'>
'23ecf1c97b1eb5d94a25dc677ec464e5'

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\MonitorSoft\MonitorSoft.py", line 201, in LoadSQL
    CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3],))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @sia: you need to show us the type of the value that throws the exception, not the ones that are successful.

Comment: type of the value  that throws the exception also "str".  This value gives an exeption <class 'str'> '23ecf1c97b1eb5d94a25dc677ec464e5'

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, the very first step should be to print out all of your immediate values, so you can verify they are what you think they are. As a side effect, this makes your select statement much easier to read.

For example:

```
selection = WinRedactor.Table.selection()
print("selection is", selection)
first_selection = selection[0]
print("first selection is", first_selection)
values = WinRedactor.Table.item(first_selection, option='values')
print("values are", values)
checksum = values[3]
print("checksum:", checksum)

CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (checksum,))
```

My guess is, you'll be surprised at what you see. At the very least, you've have more data to put into your question so that we know precisely what the data is.