# Interface Error importing pandas dataframe to sqlite: Unsupported parameter

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have an excel workbook which has two worksheets. I want to import these two worksheets data in two different pandas data frame and then write it to sqlite database.

Here is the code for the same.

```
leads_dim = pd.read_excel('client_data.xlsx',sheetname='Lead_Dimension')
leads_dim.to_sql('leads_dim', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

# Reading the Sales Fact table
sales_fact = pd.read_excel('client_data.xlsx',sheetname='Sales_Fact')
sales_fact.to_sql('sales_fact', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

But this seems to give me this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-2a90986d22b9> in <module>()
      4 # Reading the Sales Fact table
      5 sales_fact = pd.read_excel('client_data.xlsx',sheetname='Sales_Fact')
----> 6 sales_fact.to_sql('sales_fact', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in to_sql(self, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    980             self, name, con, flavor=flavor, schema=schema, if_exists=if_exists,
    981             index=index, index_label=index_label, chunksize=chunksize,
--> 982             dtype=dtype)
    983 
    984     def to_pickle(self, path):

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(frame, name, con, flavor, schema, if_exists, index, index_label, chunksize, dtype)
    547     pandas_sql.to_sql(frame, name, if_exists=if_exists, index=index,
    548                       index_label=index_label, schema=schema,
--> 549                       chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
    550 
    551 

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in to_sql(self, frame, name, if_exists, index, index_label, schema, chunksize, dtype)
   1565                             dtype=dtype)
   1566         table.create()
-> 1567         table.insert(chunksize)
   1568 
   1569     def has_table(self, name, schema=None):

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in insert(self, chunksize)
    726 
    727                 chunk_iter = zip(*[arr[start_i:end_i] for arr in data_list])
--> 728                 self._execute_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
    729 
    730     def _query_iterator(self, result, chunksize, columns, coerce_float=True,

/Users//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter)
   1355     def _execute_insert(self, conn, keys, data_iter):
   1356         data_list = list(data_iter)
-> 1357         conn.executemany(self.insert_statement(), data_list)
   1358 
   1359     def _create_table_setup(self):

InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 10 - probably unsupported type.
```

Need to fix this asap and this is holding me from doing anything. Please advise.

EDIT 1:

First few lines of sales_fact table.

```
    LeadId  AccountId   LeadCreatedDate AccountCreatedDateTime  CustomerCity    CustomerPostalCode  CustomerCountry ArrivalDate DepartureDate   DealWonSalesPersonId    LeadCreatedTime SalesPersonId   DealWonId   BookingCreatedDate  ProductId   GrossRevenue    EngineFromFinalUrl  CampaignFromFinalUrl    AdgroupFromFinalUrl KwmtFromFinalUrl    GrossProfitPotential
0   143 201567  2014-06-11 10:59:09.633000  2011-08-12 15:07:52.557000  Rocky Point 28457-9585  USA 2016-10-02 12:00:00 2016-10-09 11:59:00 88285   10:59:09.633000 88285   23796   2015-10-04 05:58:03.040000  15438   1169    GO  Remarket Tuscany    Tuscany Remarketing List    none    538.9800
1   157 89412   2014-06-11 13:18:58.640000  2008-01-12 14:31:51.957000  ELK GROVE   95624-6060  USA 2015-05-03 12:00:00 2015-05-06 11:59:00 50868   13:18:58.640000 50868   22985   2014-09-30 13:43:03 6889    1877    r.search.yahoo.com  none    none    none    770.9893
2   216 302758  2014-06-12 08:22:05.377000  2014-04-12 06:18:35.417000  Mound   55364   USA 2014-09-27 12:00:00 2014-10-04 11:59:00 50868   08:22:05.377000 50868   22778   2014-06-18 11:34:02.373000  20625   11940   MS  IT-Tuscany  it_tuscany_villa    none    5815.0796
3   216 302758  2014-06-12 08:22:05.377000  2014-04-12 06:18:35.417000  Mound   55364   USA 2014-09-20 12:00:00 2014-09-27 11:59:00 50868   08:22:05.377000 50868   22764   2014-06-14 10:41:14.510000  20627   9887    MS  IT-Tuscany  it_tuscany_villa    none    2944.4258
4   527 293302  2014-06-14 07:37:43.637000  2014-01-23 05:05:58.910000  Manchester Center   05255   USA 2015-10-10 12:00:00 2015-10-24 11:59:00 159707  07:37:43.637000 159707  23137   2014-12-15 13:26:44 15152   3423    email   New_Living_Local_Provence   newsletter-june13-14    none    923.0000
```

Comment: Did you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251675/sqlite-3-sqlite-interfaceerror-error-binding-parameter-0-probably-unsupporte)? And have you tried writing a minimal dataframe to sqlite just to check your bindings?

Comment: I was able to import an excel file earlier as data frame. This one is giving error]

Comment: And not sure if this link helped much. :(. It doesn't talk about what could be the problem causing this

Comment: But the error is not on reading the spreadsheet. It is in the 'to_SQL' call. So, can you write to SQL with a simple, mock data frame?

Comment: Sorry.. Yes ._to_sql works fine. I have earlier used a data set to write to that

Comment: Please show the output of `sales_fact.info()` and `sales_fact.head()`. (or even better, provide some data that can reproduce the problem)

Comment: Ok I have added the output of first few lines. And yes if I just try to import only these too, it gives the same error. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message is probably that you have a column with times (`datetime.time` objects). These are not supported using the sqlite3 connection fallback (but will be in the upcoming pandas release, see [PR](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11547)).

If you use an SQLAlchemy engine to specify the database connection, this will work:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite://path/to/file.db")
sales_fact.to_sql('sales_fact', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

See here for the documentation on how to specify the connection with `create_engine`: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Comment: Just a question.Sqlalchemy also uses sqlite as the database to store the data right? Just a connect is different?

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's a kind of abstraction layer around the different database drivers, but you are still using a sqlite database in this case